# Regain access to my broken Gmail account from Temporary Error 500, Numeric Code 93

Tags: gmail

Since August 1st I've been getting this error when trying to login to my gmail account:

> Temporary Error (500)
>
> We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes.
>
> If the issue persists, please visit the Gmail Help Center »
>
> Try Again Sign Out
>
> Hide Detailed Technical Info
>   Numeric Code: 93

I've emailed Gmail support several times with no response after their autoresponder, and I've posted to the [Gmail help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=355e6019a39f8827&hl=en&fid=355e6019a39f88270004aa294b5f822c).

Absolutely no response.  It's been more than 10 days now, and I'm starting to get desperate!

Can anyone give me any ideas for how I might get this issue resolved.  If any Googlers happen to read this – you'll receive much good karma if you notify one of the engineers of my plight! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Occasionally a 500 error can be caused by corrupted code in your browser, but most often these are errors that need to be fixed by the Gmail team.

You can try:

- Clearing your cache and cookies
- POP or IMAP
- The basic HTML version of
  Gmail

If none of these work, then the error is a problem affecting your account and which needs to be fixed on the Google side.

I am sorry we missed your post in the Help Forum and I have replied there.

Comment: Hi Sarah,

Thanks for your response! (I posted a reply to your question about my account in the forum).

I've tried different browsers on different computers (including clearing cache/cookies), I've tried POP/IMAP access, and I've tried logging into the mobile version from my iphone -- no luck.  I think it is a problem on the Google side.

Comment: Hi Sarah, Have you checked that forum post lately?  I'm on day 16 of my outage, and other gmail users are starting to chime in to the thread with similar problems.  Is anyone working on this?  We'd all love an update in the forum...

Answer (score 6):

You could setup a desktop client such as Thunderbird or Outlook to use IMAP and try to get your email that way. Here is a [guide from Gmail](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725).

I guess another hack would be to try to creat a new Google account and then link you old one to it ([multiple sign-on](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776) is what Google calls it) and see if you can get your email that way.

Comment: Already tried that.  I can't even authenticate via IMAP/POP. :-(